# How to Hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I am finding uniques URL in a log file along with the response stamp which can be available using $line[7]. I am using Hash to get the unique URLs.

1. How can I get the count of Unique URL?
2. How can I get the average of response time along with the count of Unique URL?

With below code I am getting

```
url1
url2
url3
```

but I want it along with the average response time and count of each URL

```
URL     Av.RT   Count
url1    10.5    125
url2    9.3     356
url3    7.8     98
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(IN, "web1.txt") or die "can not open file";

# Hash to store final list of unique IPs
my %uniqueURLs = ();
my $z; 
# Read log file line by line
while (<IN>) {
@line = split(" ",$_);
$uniqueURLs{$line[9]}=1;
}

# Go through the hash table and print the keys
# which are the unique IPs
for $url (keys %uniqueURLs) {
print $url . "\n";
}
```

Comment: You should use indentation, it will make your code much more readable. Also, you should always use `use strict; use warnings;` to avoid typos and get feedback on your errors.

Answer (score 2):

store a listref in your hashing directory:

```
$uniqueURLs{$line[9]} = [ <avg response time>, <count> ];
```

adjust the elements accordingly, eg. the count:

```
if (defined($uniqueURLs{$line[9]})) {
    # url known, increment count,
    # update average response time with data from current log entry
    $uniqueURLs{$line[9]}->[0] =
        (($uniqueURLs{$line[9]}->[0] * $uniqueURLs{$line[9]}->[1]) + ($line[7] + 0.0))
           / ($uniqueURLs{$line[9]}->[1] + 1)
    ;
    $uniqueURLs{$line[9]}->[1] += 1;
}
else {
    # url not yet known,
    # init count with 1 and average response time with actual response time from log entry 
    $uniqueURLs{$line[9]} = [ $line[7] + 0.0, 1 ];
}
```

to print results:

```
# Go through the hash table and print the keys
# which are the unique IPs
for $url (keys %uniqueURLs) {
    printf ( "%s %f %d\n", $url, $uniqueURLs{$url}->[0], $uniqueURLs{$url}->[1]);
}
```

adding `0.0` will guarantee type coercion from string to float as a safeguard.

Comment: Hi I have tried with your suggestion but Average Response time is 0 and URL count is 1. Here is what I have tried

Comment: @user2060430: it works with me. potential sources for trouble: `split` actually takes a regular expression as its first argument ( ie. `split(/[[:space:]]+/,$_);` to split at whitespace sequences ); base for array indexing is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). Also, read up on [modern Perl practices](http://modernperl.net) which will help improve your programming skills.

Instead of just using the keys of your hash of unique URLs, you could store information in those hashes. Let's start with just a count of the unique URLs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    WEB_FILE => "web1.txt",
};

open my $web_fh, "<", WEBFILE;   #Autodie will catch this for you
my %unique_urls;
while ( my $line = <$web_fh> ) {
    my $url = (split /\s+/, $line)[9];
    if ( not exists $unique_urls{$url} ) {  #Not really needed
        $unique_urls{$url} = 0;
    }
    $unique_urls{$url} += 1;
}
close $web_fh;
```

Now, each key in your %unique_urls hash will contain the number of unique URLs you have.

This, by the way, is your code written in a bit more modern style. The [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) *pragmas* will catch about 90% of the standard programming errors. The [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) will catch exceptions to things that you forget to check. In this case, the program will automatically die if the file doesn't exist.

The three parameter version of the `open` command is preferred, and so is using scalar variables for file handles. Using scalar variables for the file handle makes them easier to pass in subroutines, and the file will automatically close if the file handle [falls out of scope](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29).

However, we want to store in two items per hash. We want to store the unique count, and we want to store something that will help us find the *average* response time. This is where *references* come in.

In Perl, variables deal with single data items. A *scalar* variable (like `$foo`) deals with an individual data item. Arrays and Hashes (like `@foo` and `%foo`) deal with lists of individual data items. References help you get around this limitation.

Let's look at an array of people:

```
$person[0] = "Bob";
$person[1] = "Ted";
$person[2] = "Carol";
$person[3] = "Alice";
```

However, people are more than just first names. They have last names, phone numbers, addresses, etc. Let's take a look at a hash for Bob:

```
my %bob_hash;
$bob_hash{FIRST_NAME} = "Bob";
$bob_hash{LAST_NAME} = "Jones";
$bob_hash{PHONE} = "555-1234";
```

We can take a *reference* to this hash by putting a backslash in front of it. A reference is merely the memory address where this hash is stored:

```
$bob_reference = \%bob_hash;
print "$bob_reference\n":   # Prints out something like HASH(0x7fbf79004140)
```

However, that memory address is a single item, and could be stored in our array of people!

```
$person[0] = $bob_reference;
```

If we want to get to the items in our reference, we *dereference* it by putting the right data type symbol in front. Since this is a hash, we will use `%`:

```
$bob_hash = %{ $person[0] };
```

Perl provides an easy way to dereference hashes with the `->` syntax:

```
$person[0]->{FIRST_NAME} = "Bob";
$person[0]->{LAST_NAME}  = "Jones";
$person[0]->{PHONE}  = "555-1212";
```

We'll use the same technique in `%unique_urls` to store the number of times, and the total amount of response time. (Average will be total time / number of times).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    WEB_FILE => "web1.txt",
};

open my $web_fh, "<", WEB_FILE;   #Autodie will catch this for you
my %unique_urls;
while ( my $line ( <$web_fh> ) {
    my $url = (split /\s+/, $line)[9];
    my $response_time = (split /\s+/, $line)[10];   #Taking a guess        
    if ( not exists $unique_urls{$url} ) {  #Not really needed
        $unique_urls{$url}->{INSTANCES} = 0;
        $unique_urls{$url}->{TOTAL_RESP_TIME} = 0;
    }
    $unique_urls{$url}->{INSTANCES} += 1;
    $unique_urls{$url}->{TOTAL_RESP_TIME} += $response_time;
}
$close $web_fh;
```

Now we can print them out:

```
print "%20.20s  %6s  %8s\n", "URL", "INST", "AVE";
for my $url ( sort keys %unique_urls ) {
    my $total_resp_time = $unique_urls{$url}->{TOTAL_RESP_TIME};
    my $instances = $unique_urls{$url}->{INSTANCES};
    my $average = $total_resp_time / $instances
    printf "%-20.20s  %-6d  %-8.5f\n", $url, $instances, $average";
}
```

I like using [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) for tables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the value to 1 here:

```
$uniqueURLs{$line[9]}=1;
```

Store a data structure indicating the response time and the number of times this URL has been seen (so you can properly calculate the average). You can use an array ref, or hashref if you want. If the key doesn't exist yet, that means it hasn't been seen yet, and you can set some initial values.

```
# Initialize 3-element arrayref: [count, total, average]
$uniqueURLS{$line[9]}       = [0, 0, 0] if not exists $uniqueURLS{$line[9]};
$uniqueURLs{$line[9]}->[0]++;           # Count
$uniqueURLs{$line[9]}->[1] += $line[7]; # Total time
# Calculate average
$uniqueURLs{$line[9]}->[2]  = $uniqueURLs{$line[9]}->[1] / $uniqueURLs{$line[9]}->[0];
```

One way you can get count of uniqueURLS is by counting the keys:

```
print scalar(keys %uniqueURLS); # Print number of unique url's
```

In your loop, you can print out the url and average time like this:

```
for $url (keys %uniqueURLs) {
   print $url, ' - ', $uniqueURLs[$url]->[2], "seconds \n";
}
```